# Merry Xmas to all :)

Tags: discussion, subjective-questions, meta

There’s no question in this question, and whether you believe/like/hate/ignore/etc., this is a time where a lot of people stays with family and such. I can’t because mine is on the other side of the world, but in any case, I wish all of you happy holidays.

Don’t drink and drive and reload your energies because next year we’ll have a lot of questions to answer :)

Thanks to all who voted up/down and participated in the community so far.

Comment: *note*: I had to fill a captcha to submit the above :)

Comment: Hello fellow robot! Merry Christmas to you!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: That a big Touche!

Answer (score 3):

[image]
<sub>(source: [themaclawyer.com](http://www.themaclawyer.com/uploads/image/Merry%20Christmas%202008.png))</sub>

## Merry Christmas!